# Ansible playbook syntax help from CLI

Tags: ansible

I would like to know all the ways i can get information about ansible from CLI.
The help sources i know of are:

1- these "few" man pages:

```
ansible (1)          
ansible-config (1)   
ansible-console (1)  
ansible-doc (1)      
ansible-galaxy (1)   
ansible-inventory (1)
ansible-playbook (1) 
ansible-pull (1)     
ansible-vault (1)
```

2- the ansible-doc command that only provides help about modules.

What seems missing to me for example is information about playbook syntax. If i want to verify the syntax of a loop or to see what loop mechanisms are available ...

Answer (score 2):

Documentation for ansible is available on their website, rooted at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html

You can navigate from there to, for example, the page on [playbook overview](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html)  or [loop mechanisms](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html).

If you run ansible [from source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible), you can make a local copy of the documentation in html format by descending into docs/docsite and issuing `make viewdocs` (requires [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) installed on your system).

Comment: I am perfectly aware of ansible's online documentation, my question is about how to locate such information from "CLI". Same as for modules it is much easier to do ansible-doc module_name then to have to go online (assuming you have internet access) and search the documentation website

Comment: As I note in the third paragraph, you don't need internet access: the source for docs.ansible.com is all included in the distribution, so you can read it locally via a graphical or, if you prefer, text-based html reader.  Ansible clearly favors web-oriented documentation: each of the relatively brief man pages ends with "extensive documentation available at...".

Comment: I will be taking redhat's ansible certification exam in a few weeks, there will be definitely no internet connection available, I assume ansible will be installed from the standard repository packages. When i prepare for exams i usually do not count on memorizing materials by heart i rather try to always know where to look for the info when i need it. With ansible, i can't figure out where to look for information about magic-variables, loops, conditionals ... If your method still applies in exam conditions can you elaborate? , i don't suppose typing make viewdocs in the terminal will be enough